# Performance degradation using function pointers with TBB

Tags: c++, data-structures, function-pointers, tbb

I am trying to execute a function inside a structure using TBB.

```
#include<tbb/tbb.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<time.h>

const int size = 10000000;

struct add{
    float operator()(const float &x, const float& y)const {
        return x + y;
    }
};

std::vector<float>A(size);
std::vector<float>B(size);

template<typename Function, typename First, typename Second, typename Last>
struct Make{
    Function function;
    First first;
    Second second;
    Last last;
    Make(Function _function) :function(_function){}
    void operator()(int i) const {
        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int j = 0; j < size / 10; j++){
            last[j + i*size / 10] = function(first[j + i*size / 10], second[j + i*size / 10]);
        }
        clock_t end = clock();
        std::cout << (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    }
};


template<typename FirstVector, typename SecondVector, typename Func>
void execute_tbb(place p, FirstVector First, SecondVector Second, Func func){
    struct Make<Func, FirstVector, SecondVector, SecondVector> make(func);
    make.first = First;
    make.second = Second;
    make.last = Second;
    clock_t start = clock();
    tbb::parallel_for(0, 10, 1, make);
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
}

void foo(int i){
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int j = 0; j < size / 10; j++){
        B[j + i*size / 10] = A[j + i*size / 10] + B[j + i*size / 10];
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::fill(A.begin(), A.end(), 1);
    std::fill(B.begin(), B.end(), 2);
    execute_tbb(A.begin(), B.begin(), add());

    clock_t start = clock();
    tbb::parallel_for(0, 10, 1, foo);
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code is referenced from [example under complexity](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_for_func.htm).

**Issue:** The structure `add` is performing very poor by a factor of 0.0002 compared to `foo`

**Working**: The main function passes data and function to `execute_tbb()`. It then uses `struct Make` to setup data and functions to be executed in a format runnable by `tbb::parallel_for`. The `function` in `struct Make` stores the executable function `add` and is executed by `tbb::parallel_for` in `execute_tbb`.

`$ g++ add.cpp -ltbb -o add`

Comment: I see no function pointers. There are a couple of levels of indirection and some copying of objects though. (Also, `add::operator()` is unlikely to be inlined, and a function call is way more expensive than plain addition.)

Comment: @molbdnilo: I used the variable functor initially as function pointer. Then, changed it just a function. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Are you suggesting to try inlining add?

Comment: @Yakk: I wasn't using any compiler flags. Just `-ltbb` for linking.

Comment: @Yakk: Can you explain the apples and oranges part?

Comment: @Fr34K Hmm.  The problems are solved, or I misread some of your code (I thought I saw two different `tbb` functions being called).  Your remaining problem: you profiled without optimizing.  Do a `-O3` and `-O2` run.  In one case, you are accessing the vector via `std::vector::operator[]`, and in the other you are doing it via `std::vector::iterator::operator[]`.  While logically equivalent, without optimization they could differ.  Also missing is the fact that profiling A then B is way different than profiling B: by the time you get to `B`, you have just touched the entire vector!

Comment: @Yakk: I'll tryout the optimizations. I have tried commenting out A and B so that only one executes. I am getting the same performance figures. Yes, what you have mentioned about A and B is right. I have encountered them in several other of my programs. But not here.

Comment: @Yakk: It worked with `-O2`. How should I change the code so that specification of optimization during compilation is not needed? I mean, how to use `std::vector::operator[]` to `add` than `std::vector::iterator::operator[]`

Comment: Try passing `A.data()` and `B.data()` instead of `.begin()`.  That gives you raw pointers into the vector buffer, instead of (possibly checked) iterators.

Comment: @Yakk: Is there a possible way to get from iterators?

Comment: @Fr34K Get a pointer to an element?  Sure: `static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category,std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value,"only contiguous iterators please"); auto* pt = std::addressof(*it)`.  (The test is not sufficient, as we need contiguous iterators, not just random access ones: detecting if an iterator is contiguous is not currently exposed in C++.  But all contiguous iterators are random access).  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4183.pdf

Comment: @Yakk: Thank you!! :) Can I create a shared library for the functions with `-O2` and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that under default optimization, your `vector<?>::iterator::operator[]`s are much slower than `vector<?>::operator[]`.

The right fix is to compile with `-O2` or `-O3` -- optimize things before you profile them.  Code compiled without optimization turned on is intended for debugging of non-performance issues only.

An easy fix is to replace your calls to `A.begin()` with `A.data()` and similar for `B.begin()`, replacing iterator access with raw pointer access.  Then without optimization, I'm guessing `[]` on a pointer will be at least as fast as a `vector::operator[]`.